# separate values of a textbox and place it on an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a textbox in which a user its going to input a value which I want to take and do the following. I want to be able to separate each word and add something to the end of them. so if they put 123. I want to separate it and make it 1.jpg, 2,jpg 3.jpg
after they are separated i want to put it in an array to compare to another array and go from there.
Here is what I got so far

```
<input type="text" id="textfromuser" />
<script type = "text/javascript">
function validate(){
var lists = [];
var VAlidation = document.getElementById("textfromuser").value;
lists.push(VAlidation);
for(var i=0; i<lists.length; i++)
alert(lists[i]).split('.');
```

this part of the code was to show that the value in the textbox is split and placed in an array but its not working.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing arrays and strings, the value you obtain from the input is a string and you're afterwards adding it to the *lists* array and iterating over that array.

May be this is what you were looking for

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="textfromuser" />
```

Javascript

```
function validate(){
  // empty array
  var ar = [];
  // obtain a string from the input "text" field, retrieved by the "id" attribute
  var VAlidation = document.getElementById("textfromuser").value;
  // split the string into a character array
  var lists = VAlidation.split('');
  // iterate over the character array
  for(var i=0; i<lists.length; i++){
    // create a string concatenating the array's element and '.jpg'
    var str = lists[i]+'.jpg';
    // add the string var to the array
    ar.push(str);
  }
  return ar;
}
```

I created a jsfiddle to test it quickly if you want a try
http://jsfiddle.net/kpw23/2/

**UPDATE**

To compare arrays there are many ways to accomplish it. A simple way to achieve this would be to serialize the arrays and compare the serialized strings:

```
// having two arrays
var list = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg'];
var list2 = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg'];
// "Serialize" the arrays, the join() method 
/// joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string
serlist = list.join();
serlist2 = list2.join();
// Compare both serialized arrays
if(serlist==serlist2){
 alert("Arrays are equal");
}  
else{
 alert("Arrays are not equal");
}
```

This method will only work if the arrays are sorted the same way and contain exactly the same entries in the same array positions.

Comment: How can I add words to the ends thou? because I can do alert(lists[i]+".jpg"); and that shows what I need but only in the alert, if I want each element in that array to have something added to it so I can compare it to another array???

Comment: to add to the end I did... var lists = [];                         var textvalue=getelementbyID                                      lists = textvalue.split('');   and I can do the following if i want to manipulate the lists array                                for(var i=0; i<lists.length; i++){

Comment: You may use *.push()* method in a new array as you did with *VAlidation* and *list* in your example. In order to compare two arrays i think this will a subject to open a new question as there are many ways and depends on what you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Your alerting the value of `lists[i]`, not `lists[i].split('.')`. Try:

```
alert(lists[i].split('.'));
```